# MySql Query to add column with random Yes or No

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I know this seems like a super easy question but for the life of me I cannot figure it out and when I google it, the only answers that I get just deal with getting a random number. I'm learning MySql/Workbench. I am trying to write a query for one of my tables to add a column (easy enough). But my goal is to population each row with a Random Boolean (yes or no). As I previously said, everywhere I look, it only deals with getting a random number but I just need the rows to have a Random yes or no. Thank you for any suggestions or help

Answer (score 2):

If you want a random `0` or `1` (for No and Yes respectively) then all you need is to compare the result of the function [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) with `0.5`:

```
select *, 
  rand() < 0.5 as randomcol
from tablename
```

If you want to get `No` or `Yes` then use a `CASE` expression:

```
select *, 
  case when rand() < 0.5 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as randomcol
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Populating rows of a table with random values can be accomplished by 'getting a random number' and then using `% 2` on the results to clamp it either 0 or 1.  Then just insert it into the desired tables / columns.

For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO "your_table" ("col1","col2","random") 
VALUES ("val1", "val2",(RAND()*1000)%2)
```

This would add rows with constant values for `col1` and `col2` into `your_table`, but the `random` column will get populated with a random number between 0-999, which we then get the modulus of 2 to clamp the final result to either 0 or 1.

Also, if you want to make the values generated random but consistent, you can pass in a seed to make the sequence of generated values repeatable (ie `RAND(10)` will always produce the same result, so you can use an incrementing seed to produce psudo-random results that you can consistently repeat).